# Can't include <gl/gl.h>

Tags: opengl, include, redefinition

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.
I'm trying to write simple Camera class in OpenGL.
I need to include gl/gl.h in Camera.h
gl/gl.h is already included in main.cpp and Camera.h is included in main.cpp
When I put

```
#include <gl/gl.h>
```

in Camera.h i got bunch of errors like this one:
`Error    11    error C2086: 'int APIENTRY' : redefinition    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\gl\GL.h    1153    1    Gaz 3D`

files:
Camera.h

```
#include <math.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>

#ifndef _CAMERA_H
#define _CAMERA_H

class Camera
{
private:
    Camera();
public:
    static Camera& getCamera();
    float x, y, z, rotv, roth;
    void moveForward(float n);
    void moveBackward(float n);
    void moveLeft(float n);
    void moveRight(float n);
    void lookUp(float n);
    void lookDown(float n);
    void lookLeft(float n);
    void lookRight(float n);
};

#endif
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl\gl.h>
#include <gl\glu.h>
#include <gl\glaux.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "Camera.h"

// ... some variables ...

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,  
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // main code ...
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think that this is causing your problem, so I won't post it as an answer: `#include <math.h>` and `#include <gl/gl.h>` should be inside of the `#ifndef` guard in Camera.h.

On second thought, you don't even need those includes in that header at all; you aren't using anything from them in the declaration of Camera.

Comment: I'm not but I will be using math and gl.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just do an include of windows.h first.

```
#include <windows.h>
```

As it's said in the OpenGL FAQ :

> Also, note that you'll need to put an `#include <windows.h>` statement before the `#include<GL/gl.h>`. Microsoft requires system DLLs to use a specific calling convention that isn't the default calling convention for most Win32 C compilers, so they've annotated the OpenGL calls in gl.h with some macros that expand to nonstandard C syntax. This causes Microsoft's C compilers to use the system calling convention.  One of the include files included by windows.h defines the macros.

---

**Resources :**

- [social.msdn.microsoft.com - OpenGL problems](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/5fa6bbe2-32db-49e2-a643-5db082f972e6)
- [OpenGL FAQ - Why am I getting compile, link, and runtime errors?](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/gettingstarted.htm#0020)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Obviously Colin Hebert solved the problem, but as a general tip I`d like to say:

In Camera.h write

```
#ifndef _CAMERA_H
#define _CAMERA_H
```

**above** all other includes.
And include all header files needed in your .cpp file in your .h file.

At least that`s what I think is best practice.

Comment: This should make no differences. The GL headers have an inclusion guard as well.

Comment: That was rather meant as a general tip.

Comment: if it wasn't meant to solve the user's problem, you should say so. As it is, it sounds like you're answering his question, and the answer is wrong.

Comment: @LarsH okay, sorry, did as you told me.